# Overloading operator+ multiple times in same statement

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have the following code to overload `operator+`, which works fine when the program gets executed.

In the `main()` function, when I re-write the statement to call the overloaded `operator+` from `res= t + t1 + t2`, which works fine, to `res = t + (t1 + t2)`, it does not work anymore. Can anyone provide me a solution, along with the reason?

A solution already found is to update the signatures of the `operator+` from `Test operator +(Test &a)` to `Test operator +(const Test &a)`. Here, I have used the `const` keyword in the parameter list.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
private:
    int num;

public:
    Test(int v)
    {
        num = v;
    }

    Test operator+(Test &a)
    {
        Test r(0);
        r = num + a.num;
        return r;
    }

    void show()
    {
        cout << "\n num = " << num;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Test t(10);
    Test t1(20);
    Test t2(60);

    Test res(0);
    res = t + t1 + t2;
    res.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the basic rules and idioms for operator overloading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you are accepting an object by non-const reference, not by `const` reference.

The `Test` object returned by `operator+()` is a temporary. [A non-const reference can't bind to a temporary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/).

The reason this was probably working before is the `operator+` was executed from left to right - which would look something like this:

```cpp
object + object + object
temporary + object
```

The temporary still has the function `operator+()`, so it can still be called.

On the other hand, when you use parenthesis, it executes like this:

```cpp
object + object + object
object + temporary
```

That means that the temporary ends up in `a`, which, again, can't happen for the reasons stated above.

To fix, either a) turn it into a `const` reference, or b) pass by value (not recommended because it creates extra copies in memory you don't need):

```cpp
// a
Test operator +(const Test &a) 
// b
Test operator +(Test a)
```

I also highly recommend making this function a `const` as well:

```cpp
// a
Test operator +(const Test &a) const
// b
Test operator +(Test a) const
```

Now you can add `const` objects even if they are on the right hand side as well.

Answer (score 1):

`(t1 + t2)` evaluates to an rvalue expression.

But your `operator+(&)` can only bind to non-const lvalues. On the other hand `const &` can bind to both lvalues and rvalues, thus `operator+(const &)` works.